# Color tick mark & tick mark labels in sliderinput - Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to give different colors for the tick marks and tick mark labels in the sliderinput in shiny dashboard. ex : 0 to 5 - red, 5 to 10 - blue. My code is not working.

Please check my code,

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", ".irs-grid-pol-left {color: red; width:50%;}",
               ".irs-grid-pol-right {color: blue; width: 50%; left: 50%;}"),
    sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 1, 10, 1)
  ),
  server <- function(input, output) {}  
)
```

Thanks,
SJB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of a `css` issue than `R` or `Shiny`. This should do the work:

```
library(shiny)    
shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", 
               ".irs-grid-text:nth-child(-2n+18) {color: red}",
               ".irs-grid-text:nth-child(2n+20) {color: blue}",
               ".irs-grid-pol:nth-of-type(-n+18) {background:red}",
               ".irs-grid-pol:nth-of-type(n+18) {background:blue}"),
    sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", 1, 10, 1)
  ),
  server <- function(input, output) {}
```

[image]

If you need to further customize it, open the style editor in your browser, tweak the numbers, and update the string in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i need a clarification, what does this line of code mean: nth-child(-2n+18)

Comment: It selects specific DOM elements, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)